# Writing a difficult query for MS-Access (without MINUS operation, 3 table join)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've come here for help with a complicated query. I've tried a lot of different things for this and not quite got the results that I want. A watered down version of my schema is as follows: The three tables in question are an Employees Table, an EmployeeTraining Table, and a RequiredTraining table. The employees table holds information of an employee, such as empID,name, address, email, positionWorked, etc etc. The EmployeeTraining table holds an empID, and TrainingName.The RequiredTraining table has a Position and TrainingName.

Employees: **empID**,
             Name,
             Position

EmployeeTraining: **empID**,
                  **trainingName**

requiredTraining:  **Position**,
                   **trainingName**

Here's some sample data, just to further clarify:

**Employees**

```
              *EMPID~~Name~~Position~~
                  1      Ted     Accountant

                  2      Bob     Janitor
```

**employeeTraining**

```
                 **empID~~TrainingName**
                    1          Crunching Numbers

                    1          Microsoft Excel

                    1          Using an Abicus

                    2          Lemon Pledge 100

                    2          Scrubbing Toilets
```

**requiredTraining**

```
                  **position**~~**TrainingName**


                    Accountant    Crunching Numbers

                    Accountant    Microsoft Excel

                    Accountant    Using an Abicus

                    Accountant    TPS Reports

                    Janitor       Lemon Pledge 100

                    Janitor       Scrubbing Toilets
```

In english, and in the long run, I want to select an employee from a form and have a subform showing all of the training completed from that employee(SELECT * FROM Employees INNER JOIn EmployeeTraining on employees.empid = employeetraining.empID WHERE empID = me.empID)

I also want another subform that shows the training that an employee has NOT completed that is required for their current position. This is where I am struggling. I am not familiar or comfortable with using MS Access's query builder, but I have tried "find unmatched" queries as well as trying to write my own. This seems like a MINUS operation would work, but MS Access doesn't support MINUS. I have tried a LEFT JOIN with a null predicate as well as a NOT IN from the above query to a query of the requiredTraining table, but I haven't got the results I'm looking for.

For example, the result of the query I'm trying to write for this sample data would be:

for employeeID 1 (Ted the Accountant)

ted needs "TPS Reports" training

for employee 2 ( Bob the Janitor)

Bob has completed all of his training for his position.

An example of an attempted query I am trying is:

```
      SELECT employees.position,employeeTraining.empid,employeetraining.TrainingName          
      FROM EmployeeTraining 
      InNER JOIN Employees ON EmployeeTraining.empid = employees.empid
      WHERE empid = '1'
      LEFT JOIN
      SELECT TrainingName,Position FROM requiredTraining
      ON EmployeeTraining.Training = RequiredTraining.Training
      WHERE (((EmployeeTraining.Training is Null)))
```

Edit: This question has been answered. Thanks everyone for the help. Your queries, although each was different, all accomplished the goal.

Comment: The left join is the answer - what left join code did you use, and what did you feel was wrong with the answer?

Comment: I was somewhere around "SELECT employeeID, employeeTraining.trainingname FROM employeeTraining LEFT JOIN RequiredTraining on employeeTraining.TrainingName = requiredTraining.TrainingName WHERE (((employeeTraining.trainingName is Null))) And empID = [me.empID]        My Query is not returning any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below is created from two MS Access queries with the SQL cut and pasted into derived tables. The two queries select the employee with their current training (#1) and the employee with their required training (#2). It is not updateable, but is easy to create. You can show only the missing training by adding a line at the end:

```
WHERE et.TrainingName Is Null
```

To select a single employee, you can add a line:

```
WHERE rt.EMPID=1 AND et.TrainingName Is Null
```

However, you mention a subform, so I expect you will wish to use link child and master fields to limit by employee.

SQL

```
SELECT rt.empid,
       rt.position,
       rt.trainingname,
       et.trainingname AS IsTrained
FROM   (SELECT employees.empid,
               requiredtraining.position,
               requiredtraining.trainingname
        FROM   employees
               INNER JOIN requiredtraining
                       ON employees.position = requiredtraining.position) AS rt
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT employees.empid,
                         employees.position,
                         employeetraining.trainingname
                  FROM   employees
                         INNER JOIN employeetraining
                                 ON employees.empid = employeetraining.empid) AS
                 et
              ON ( rt.trainingname = et.trainingname )
                 AND ( rt.position = et.position )
                 AND ( rt.empid = et.empid );
```

Comment: Yes, Remou.Ideally I will have a form with a lot of information about an employee. On that form will be two subforms. One with completed training, one with remaining required training. The "NOT IN" query that I discussed above works. I am in the process of sorting out the discrepancies between your example and my actual schema (I wrote a watered down example for readability). I will try your version and see if I can get it to work. I have not used subforms before, but I probably won't start coding my forms until i finish necessary queries.Thank you.

Comment: I do have one additional question about the subform. I will build the subform with the recordsource set to the query in question. To have this subform/query get the empID parameter from the parent form textbox ('empIDtxt'), how do I do this? is it "WHERE empID = [Forms]![frmParentForm]![empIDtxt]"? or is there a "WHERE empID = [me.parentForm.empIDtxt] " option or something similar?

Comment: As I mention above, use the link child and link master fields for the subform control. These are properties of the control, not the form contained by the control. If you use the wizard to create the subform control, it will prompt you for these properties. In this case, both the link child and link master fields will be EmpID.

Comment: Just made a subform with the wizard and it gave this option. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should return all employees with the training names that they need to complete:

```
select e.emp_id, rt.TrainingName
from employees e left outer join
     RequiredTraining rt
     on e.position = rt.position
where rt.TrainingName not in (select TrainingName from EmployeeTraining et where et.empId = e.EmpId)
```

The join in the "from" clause finds all the required trainings.  The "where" clause then uses a correlated subquery to find the ones the employee has not completed.

Comment: This seems close, but when I try to run the query, MS Access asks me for a value for e.empid and rt.trainingName. I added to the where clause "and e.empID = '1'" to test it, and it still asked me for an empID. Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Since you are specifying the employee id explicitly, then change the where clause on the subquery to "where et.empId = <the id>".

Answer (score 1):

you're very close actually, with your other query... you might try the NOT IN clause. For example, as you have said, you can get all the employees that have completed a particular training like so:

```
SELECT e.empID, e.name, e.Position, et.TrainingName
FROM Employees e
JOIN EmployeeTraining et ON e.empID = et.empID
WHERE empID = me.empID
```

What you want now, is all the employees that have NOT completed the training... you could just do a join on the trainingName table, making sure that the training type is not in the query you've already created, like so:

```
SELECT e.empID, e.name, e.Position, rt.TrainingName
FROM Employees e
JOIN requiredTraining rt ON e.Position = rt.Position
WHERE rt.TrainingName NOT IN
(
   SELECT et.TrainingName
   FROM Employees e
   JOIN EmployeeTraining et ON e.empID = et.empID
   WHERE empID = me.empID
)
  AND e.empID = me.empID
```

Note that, as mentioned above, you don't actually need to join on the employees table... you could just use the following:

```
SELECT e.empID, e.name, e.Position, rt.TrainingName
FROM Employees e
JOIN requiredTraining rt ON e.Position = rt.Position
WHERE rt.TrainingName NOT IN
(
   SELECT et.TrainingName
   FROM EmployeeTraining
   WHERE et.empID = me.empID
)
  AND e.empID = me.empID
```

Comment: This is helping, but MS Access is giving me syntax errors unless I specify the join type. Simply typing 'JOIN' and the 'on' condition won't satisfy it. Are all these joins you are recommending natural inner joins?

Comment: I specified inner joins for the joins. It's running the query, but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Update:When I take off the last condition 'AND e.empID = me.empID' I get all of the employeeID's that have the specified position of the specified empID along with the training that they lack(the empID in question is in that list correctly also). But for some reason, when I try to get just the one employee, I don't get any results back.

Comment: Update: it is now working. The final query is: SELECT e.empID, e.position, rt.trainingName FROM employees e INNER JOIN requiredTraining rt on e.position = rt.position WHERE rt.training NOT IN( select et.training from employees e INNER JOIN employeeTraining on e.empid = et.empid where et.empid = me.empid) and e.empid = me.empid

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns this result set based on your sample data as tested with Access 2007.

```
EMPID Position    TrainingName
1     Accountant  TPS Reports

SELECT
    sub.EMPID,
    sub.Position,
    sub.TrainingName
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            e.EMPID,
            e.Position,
            rt.TrainingName
        FROM
            Employees AS e
            INNER JOIN RequiredTraining AS rt
            ON e.Position = rt.position
    ) AS sub
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeTraining AS et
    ON
            sub.TrainingName = et.TrainingName
        AND sub.EMPID = et.empID
WHERE et.TrainingName Is Null;
```